# Changing Windows Media Center Screensaver

Tags: windows-media-center, screensaver, plasma-tv

I've enabled the picture slideshow screensaver within Windows Media Center and all was good when I had an LCD TV.  Now that I have plasma, I'm noticing some slight image retention where the white picture border is usually at.  Is there any way to change or customize the screen saver in WMC?

Ideally I would like something similar to AppleTV's Origami screensaver.